# Using assetic outside Symfony2 (with Yii)

Tags: php, yii, assetic

We want to use assetic, specifically to manage our image assets. However, I am stuck trying to figure out how to integrate assetic with the framework we use, Yii.

What I want to do is read the images located in /assets/images and write them to the folder /public/images

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
$am = new AssetManager();

$image = new FileAsset(__DIR__ . '/../../assets/images/bg-arrow.png');
$image->setTargetPath('/images/bg-arrow.jpg');

$am->set('ambassadors',$image);

$writer = new AssetWriter(__DIR__ . '/../../public');
$writer->writeManagerAssets($am);
```

This works great on a file-by-file basis. However, I wanted to know if there was a better shortcut to automatically read my image files and create individual assets out of all of them.

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to use Yii's [asset manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager) instead? See a usage example [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.create#widget).

Comment: Try using Assetic\Asset\GlobAsset

Comment: Try to use this extension https://github.com/IgorTimoshenko/IMTYiiAssetic ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Glob Asset like so:

```
use Assetic\Asset\AssetCollection;
use Assetic\Asset\GlobAsset;

$js = new AssetCollection(array(
    new GlobAsset('/path/to/js/*')
));
```